# string.Format, regex + curly braces (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

How do I use string.Format to enter a value into a regular expression, where that regular expression has curly-braces in it already to define repetition limitation? (My mind is cloudy from the collision for syntax)

*e.g.* The normal regex is "**^\d{0,2}**", and I wish to insert the '2' from the property MaxLength

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace single curly braces with double curly braces:

```
string regex = string.Format(@"^\d{{0,{0}}}", MaxLength);
```

If that makes your eyes hurt you could just use ordinary string concatenation instead:

```
string regex = @"^\d{0," + MaxLength + "}";
```

Comment: the string concatenation makes *my* eyes hurt ;)

Comment: If you don't like either of those, another option could be @"^\d{0,$MaxLength}".Replace("$MaxLength", MaxLength.ToString()). I'm not sure I like that myself because it's not C#-like, but it does keep the regular expression in readable form.

Answer (score 5):

You can escape curly braces by doubling them :

```
string.Format("Hello {{World}}") // returns "Hello {World}"
```

In your case, it would be something like that :

```
string regexPattern = string.Format("^\d{{0,{0}}}", MaxLength);
```

Answer (score 2):

For details on the formatting strings, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

```
var regex = String.Format(@"^\d{{0,{0}{1}", this.MaxLength, "}")
```

And yes, the extra parameter <strike>is</strike> *may be* required (no, it's not in this case) due to the eccentricities of the way the braces are interpreted. See the MSDN link for more.

All in all, I have to agree with Mark, just go with normal string concatenation in this case.

Comment: you're missing a closing curly brace ;)

Comment: No I'm not ;) Caught that one quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use string interpolation to do it:

```
string regex = $@"^\d{{0,{MaxLength}}}";
```

Again, you need to escape the curly braces by doubling them.